# breezejs - How to initiate complex type properties when creating a new Entity

Tags: breeze, complextype

Suppose there is person type which has some complex properties such as Address and dateOfBirth

I created a new Entity of person with this code :

```
 newPerson(manager.createEntity("Person",{ id: breeze.core.getUuid() }));
```

How can I initiate the complex type so I can bind it to a blank form?
In the breeze doc it says :http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/complextype-properties

> This is actually slightly incorrect, you can create an ‘unbound’
>   instance of a complexType with the complexType.createInstance method
>   but when you assign it, you are simply copying its values onto an
>   existing instance.

Where is the best place to initiate the complex type properties?any sample code would be so helpful.

Comment: It seams that I am mixing the complex type with  navigation properties. to ask the question in better way:  what is the best way to initiate the navigation properties when creating new entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with a scalar navigation property, i.e. a navigation property that returns a single instance of another entity, then you can do it right in the createEntity call

```
 newDetail = manager.createEntity("OrderDetail", { Order: parentOrder, Product: parentProduct });
```

If you are dealing with a nonscalar (i.e. array) navigation property then you will need to push the children into the navigation property. i.e.

```
 newCustomer = em.createEntity("Customer");
 var orders = newCustomer.getProperty("Orders"); 
 orders.push(order1);
 orders.push(order2);
 // OR
 // orders.push.apply(orders, ordersToPush);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I was wondering How SPA JumpStart is dealing with this concept on https://github.com/johnpapa/PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal.
it seams that the author johnpapa introducing a method called createNullos which could be an interesting solution.