# Breez Create Complex Entities

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, ef-code-first, breeze

I have Entity Like this

```
 public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
}

public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeePhoto { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; } 
}
```

so when I try to create new entity on breezjs on client side

```
manager.createEntity('Employee');
```

it didnt create the person entity with it that unable to bind like this

```
<input type="text"  data-ng-model="vm.employee.person.firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
```

but it show me the following error

> Cannot read property 'entityState' of undefined

Comment: Have you tried creating the person first and then creating the employee by passing an object that sets the person like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538542/breezejs-how-to-initiate-complex-type-properties-when-creating-a-new-entity

Comment: How can I do That? I donot understand the link you attach

Comment: Breeze isn't going to automatically create a person entity when you create an employee entity.  You'll need to create the person entity yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are calling a complex entity, Breeze thinks of as two related entities: Employee and Person.  As Wayne and Jeremy noted, you need to create each of them.

But there is something else: Breeze manages the relationship between the entities using their [foreign keys](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/navigation-properties#ForeignKeys).  You need to have identifiers for each of your entities, and the foreign key relationships to them.  Then your entities would look something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeePhoto { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; } // relates Employee to Person
}
```

The foreign keys are essential, because that is how Breeze can recognize the relationships between entities that are sent to and from the server.

And then you can do this:

```
var employee = manager.createEntity('Employee');
var person = manager.createEntity('Person');
employee.person = person;
```

OR you can do it this way, telling Breeze to assign the property in the initializer:

```
var person = manager.createEntity('Person');
var employee = manager.createEntity('Employee', { person: person });
```

OR you can relate the properties by personId in the initializer:

```
var person = manager.createEntity('Person');
var employee = manager.createEntity('Employee', { personId: person.personId });
```

Comment: the problem is when I try to bind like this 

data-ng-model="vm.employee.person.firstName"

it show me the following error

'firstName' is required'

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I was trying to create the entity after featch metadata, 
like this

```
this.manager.fetchMetadata()
            .then(function () {


            });
```

when I take out... it fixes